# How to generate new class or id for every MySQL record rendered to html

Tags: python, html, mysql, flask

So I have a Python (Flask) app. To be exact it's a blog app. I have a form that sends an article to MySQL database, then in my index.html page it renders each record (article). I want to add this sleek feature that on my index.html page it only shows a description, and if the visitor wants to read more, they click on read more and the whole article is given. However, since i have several articles the 'read more' button only works for one article and not the others. All articles display successfully, but the read more only works for the first displayed article. Below is my code. I also do the read more transition through javascript by targeting the ID of the div i want to expand (read more)

```
 <!-- articles -->
        {% for row in value %}
        <div class="articleRow">
           <div class="col">
                <h2>{{row[1]}}</h2>
                <p class="authorDate">Author: {{row[2]}}</p>
                <p class="authorDate">{{row[3]}}</p>
                <p class="description">{{row[4]}}</p>
                <a class="articleLink" href="">{{row[6]}}</a>
                <a class="readMore" id="readMore" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="showArticle()">Read More</a>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slideRow" id="slideRow">
            <div class="slideCol" id="slideCol">
                <article class="articleSlide" id="articleSlide">
                    {{row[5]}}
                </article>
                <a class="readLess" id="readLess" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="hideArticle()">Read Less</a> 
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}

===================================
Javascript to have readmore affect
===================================
<script>
        function openNav() {
            document.getElementById("sideNav").style.width = "300px";
        }

        function closeNav() {
            document.getElementById("sideNav").style.width = "0";
        }

        function showArticle () {
            document.getElementById("slideRow").style.height="auto";
            document.getElementById("slideCol").style.height="auto";
            document.getElementById("articleSlide").style.display="inline-block";
            document.getElementById("readMore").style.display="none";
            document.getElementById("readLess").style.display="block";
        }

        function hideArticle() {
            document.getElementById("slideRow").style.height="0";
            document.getElementById("slideCol").style.height="0";
            document.getElementById("articleSlide").style.display="none";
            document.getElementById("readMore").style.display="inline-block";
            document.getElementById("readLess").style.display="none";
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: How would I target row[0] in the javascript function?

Comment: Testing right now, give me a few minutes.

Comment: The code didnt work for me :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use JS to capture an ID, and then target that ID in a row you would want to hide.

Example:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('a.js-hide').forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const dataId = el.getAttribute('data-id')
    const contentEl = document.querySelector('#' + dataId)
    
    contentEl.style.display === "none" ? contentEl.style.display = "block" : contentEl.style.display = "none"
  })
})
```

```html
<div id="content-1">Content 1</div>
<a href="#" class="js-hide" data-id="content-1">Toggle c1</a>

<br />
<br />

<div id="content-2">Content 2</div>
<a href="#" class="js-hide" data-id="content-2">Toggle c2</a>
```

For your implementation, you can just replace `content-*` with the prefix `content-`, and then use the ID variable to make it unique. So you can use something like this: `content-{{variable.id}}` (or whatever the `ID` is in this case).